# Cross compile Pantheios for arm

Tags: arm, pantheios

I have tried to cross compile pantheios to arm but no luck. I use the arm-compiler from code sourcery.

I tried changing CC etc in the makefile for gcc46 in pantheios folder. But its says: 
"#error _STLSOFT_SIZEOF_SHORT not defined" How do i fix this?

What am i doing wrong?. does anyone know how to cross compile pantheois for arm?

Answer (score 0):

I have not ported pantheios to ARM, but I have experience porting it to PowerPC.

There is nothing to do with **pantheios** itself, it is required to update **stlsoft** library on which pantheios based. The main idea is to fix compiler platform discrimination in file stlsoft/internal/cccap/gcc.h

The required step is to add platform information into the **"Integer sizes"** section in above file.

Investigate the requiered information from your gcc cross compiler as follows

> touch file.cpp
>
> arm-crosscompiler-g++ -E -dM file.cpp > arm-gcc-def.txt

Look arm-gcc-def.txt for platform definitons (something like below):

```
#define __ARM__
#define __SIZEOF_SHORT__ 2
```

and fix stlsoft/internal/cccap/gcc.h according your findings

After that you'll be able cross compile Pantheios for ARM architecture.

Here the example patch for [PowerPC](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2503588&group_id=238860&atid=1107746) on sourceforge.

Comment: thank you for the response, it turns out i dont have to cross-compile it. The library libconfig is much easier to use and a lot easier to cross-compile. thanks again for the response

Comment: @danw you've selected another library for logging?